# What to put in OnPause to balance out what is in OnResume

Tags: android, oncreate, onpause

onResume keeps on looping until I put some sort of kill command in onPause.  In onResume I go to another activity to show a hello screen.  What should I put in onPause to stop onResume from looping?

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {

    super.onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainWelcome.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onRestart();
}
```

Hello.class

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hello_screen, options);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hello_screen, 700, 700));
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
             finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are restarting your activity every time it starts.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainWelcome.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   super.onRestart();// <----Problem there
}
```

I think you meant to call `super.onStart();`

Comment: Thanks, but the app is still looping.  Is there a way to cancel intent?

Comment: @Aaron you might want to move your intent code from `onStart` to `onPostResume`.

Comment: I tried the before and it continuously loops the hello screen.  Is there something I should put in onPause to cancel it out?

Comment: There is something wrong in your hello screen then.

Comment: I posted the code for the hello screen.  When I use intent to calls the hello class in the onCreate(), the hello screen pops up and then returns to the main activity.

Comment: You're starting a timer in your "Hello" activity that will `finish` it when it's up. That's why you are going back to the main activity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49705/discussion-between-aaron-and-yasmani-llanes)